# Amazon DataPipeline regex format

Tags: regex, amazon-data-pipeline

I have tried to parse a huge amount of logs from Amazon S3 bucket.

So far, I created and configured a sample pipe, as described in the tutorial video. However for some reason my RegEx is screwed up after the pipe is activated.

Originally, the regex was:

```
(\S+)\s...
```

and after saving it became

```
(S+)s...
```

which obviously doesn't make any sense to any regex egine I am aware of )

So can somebody please explain to me - what is the correct form of writing a regular expression for the DataPipe component?

Comment: perhaps you need to double escape?

Comment: This was the very first thing I tried - however (according to the logs) - it is passed to regex engine as double-slash, not single-slash. So still not a valid regex.

Answer (score 1):

So far - they are missing explanation of regex format. To use escape symbols - you need to put 4 backslashes, like

```
(\\\\S+)
```